# Sequelize connection to postgres refused on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I deployed my nodejs 10.16.3 app to ubuntu 18.04 from my win10 PC development. After starting the app with `pm2 start /ebs/myapp/index.js` on ubuntu, there is an error about sequelize (5.19.1) database connection:

```
$cat index-error.log
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433
    at connection.connect.err (/ebs/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:170:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/ebs/myapp/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:174:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/ebs/myapp/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:72:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 5433 },
  original:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 5433 } }
```

The postgres (11.5) is running on the same host and I can access it via command line with success.
pm2 log file also indicates that the nodejs app is listening on `port 3000`. This app front is a nginx reverse proxy which likely has nothing to do with this error.

Here is the db connection string:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('mydb', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:5433,
} );
```

Why the sequelize connection is refused?

Update: postgresql log:

```
$ cat postgresql-11-main.log
2019-10-07 20:24:27.712 UTC [665] postgres@emps ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql" at character 1
2019-10-07 20:24:27.712 UTC [665] postgres@emps STATEMENT:  psql
        ;
ubuntu@:/var/log/postgresql$ cat postgresql-11-main.log.1
2019-10-04 09:10:49.214 UTC [22809] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-10-04 09:10:49.221 UTC [22809] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-10-04 09:10:49.292 UTC [22809] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 22816) exited with exit code 1
2019-10-04 09:10:49.298 UTC [22811] LOG:  shutting down
2019-10-04 09:10:49.435 UTC [22809] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-10-04 09:11:11.561 UTC [1084] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-10-04 09:11:11.567 UTC [1084] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-10-04 09:11:11.628 UTC [1096] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-04 09:10:49 UTC
2019-10-04 09:11:11.648 UTC [1084] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-10-04 09:11:12.196 UTC [1134] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2019-10-04 09:11:17.827 UTC [1282] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2019-10-04 09:13:42.106 UTC [1084] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-10-04 09:13:42.110 UTC [1084] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-10-04 09:13:42.114 UTC [1084] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1102) exited with exit code 1
2019-10-04 09:13:42.115 UTC [1097] LOG:  shutting down
2019-10-04 09:13:42.138 UTC [1084] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-10-04 09:13:46.533 UTC [3040] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-10-04 09:13:46.535 UTC [3040] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-10-04 09:13:46.566 UTC [3041] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-04 09:13:42 UTC
2019-10-04 09:13:46.577 UTC [3040] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-10-04 09:13:47.110 UTC [3048] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2019-10-04 09:13:52.713 UTC [3082] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: Are you sure the PostgreSQL server is listening on TCP sockets too? By default, Postgres doesn't necessarily listen on TCP on UNIXes.

Comment: Could you share your `listen_addresses` from `postgresql.conf`?  If it is set to `localhost`, that would be your problem (you need to make it `*` or the specific IP address that your NodeJS app lives on)

Comment: `richyen`, the line of listen_addresses is commented out in `poastgresql.conf`.

Comment: `AKX`, the nodejs app is using module `socket.io` and the lines related to the `Socket` may come from that.

Comment: @richyen obviously from the sequelize init line the database is on the same server as the node app, your comment is out of context.

Comment: @user938363 the error you get is generic, it could be anything from wrong password to the database being down. Look into your postgres log in `/var/log/postgresql/11` and you will get a more detailed error message. If you still have trouble afterwards, add these logs to your post.

Comment: I did change the `localhost` in connection string to `127.0.0.1`. and restart the node app after cleaning pm2 log. There is no error or out log and actually there is no any log at all in both `index-error.log` and `index-out.log` (pm2) (files empty). But the 404 is the same with React Native front end (404 is not from the app customized error code). If the node app has made the connection with postgersql, then I may need to look somewhere else. The app has been fully tested in PC development.

Comment: `TheWildHealer`, the postgresql log posted. It did not give a whole lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs of your PostgreSQL server say that it is launched at the default port `5432`. But in your app you'r trying to connect to `5433`.

Try this connection instead:

```js
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('mydb', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port: 5432, // instead of 5433
} );
```

Comment: Good catch. Thank you!